# Json value append to python array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an Json object
ex: [{'fk_user_id': 50004855}, {'fk_user_id': 1}, {'fk_user_id': 1171752}, {'fk_user_id': 2}, {'fk_user_id': 44}, {'fk_user_id': 202104}]

I want the result in array as
ex:
[50004855, 1, 1171752, 2, 44, 202104]

Answer (score 1):

assuming your JSON object is now a list-of-dicts, and the values of `fk_user_id` is all you want to store, list comprehension should do the job:

```
x = [{'fk_user_id': 50004855}, {'fk_user_id': 1}, {'fk_user_id': 1171752}, {'fk_user_id': 2}, {'fk_user_id': 44}, {'fk_user_id': 202104}]

vals = [s['fk_user_id'] for s in x]
print(vals)
```

Output:

```
[50004855, 1, 1171752, 2, 44, 202104]
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this works.

Comment: @Firozz np, also if there are multiple key/value pairs and you need the values of all the keys, you could use `list(s.values())` instead, which would give u a list of lists.